# Dynamical Creating Links with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a link within a blockquote element with jQuery. Right now I'm at this stage:

```
var pullQuote = $('span.pull-quote').each(function(){

    var $this = $(this),
    hrefLink = 'http://example.com',
    text = $this.text();

    $('<blockquote>', { 
        class: 'quote',
        text: text 
    }).prependTo( $this.closest('p'));

});
```

That creates the blockquote element with the text dynamical but I want to turn the text into link inside of the blockquote. The href isn't going to change so I can set that in a variable like I already have it.

Can I add something that will create the a tag inside of the blockquote to where I can still use the set variables? (Which is what I've been trying to do) Or do I need to just run this function and then create a new function which would handle adding the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('<blockquote/>', { 
    class: 'quote',
    html: $('<a/>', {
        text: text,
        href: hrefLink
    )}
}).prependTo( $this.closest('p'));
```

If I understood you right, you just wanted to construct an anchor element within the blockquote and give that the text and the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $this = $(this);
hrefLink = 'http://example.com';
text = $this.text();

var blockQ=$('<blockquote class="quote">
                           <a href="'+hrefLink+'">'+text+'</blockquote>');
blockQ.prependTo( $this.closest('p'));
```

Demo :  http://jsfiddle.net/QGtYQ/5/