# Javascript link to div by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

So I'm seriously deficient in the Javascript department. I'm writing text to a div by but I'd like this to be a link. The text displays correctly, I'd just like to 'wrap' with a href tags?

** HTML Markup **

```
<tr>
    <td>Release Notes</td>
    <td colspan="3"><span style="color: blue;" id="releaseNotes"></span></td>                   
</tr>
```

** Part of a function **

```
$("#releaseNotes").text(('https://buildinfopage.local/app+' + (buildInformation.earVersion.substring(0, buildInformation.earVersion.indexOf('-')))));
```

Comment: You have to create an `a` element. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12939206/218196

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.html()`

Try:

```
var href = 'https://buildinfopage.local/app+' + (buildInformation.earVersion.substring(0, buildInformation.earVersion.indexOf('-')));

$("#releaseNotes").html(('<a href="'+href+'">'+href+'</a>'));
```

Comment: Tons of solutions but this was first and short and sweet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#releaseNotes").html("<a href='https://buildinfopage.local/app+" +  (buildInformation.earVersion.substring(0, buildInformation.earVersion.indexOf('-'))) + "'>Build info</a>");
```

The `.html()` method will let you replace arbitrary html to your element

Comment: The word is replace, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

```
var href = 'https://buildinfopage.local/app+' + (buildInformation.earVersion.substring(0, buildInformation.earVersion.indexOf('-')));

$("#releaseNotes").html('<a href="' + href + '" >' + href + '</a>');
```

Just need to wrap the text in a link tag. I extracted the href as a variable as we are usingit both as a link and as text

Comment: Please add an explanation of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your `div` already contains some inner elements, then you would `append` an `a` element to it:

```
var href, link;
href = 'https://buildinfopage.local/app+' + buildInformation.earVersion.substring(0, buildInformation.earVersion.indexOf('-'));
link = $("<a href='" + href + "'>" + href + "</a>");
$("#releaseNotes").append(link);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) based on your requirement

```
var href = "https://www.google.co.in";
var tag = '<a href="'+href+'" target = "_blank">'+href+'</a><br/>';
$("#releaseNotes").html(tag);
$("#releaseNotes").append(tag);
```

JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/h86N9/20/

Answer (score -1):

In span tag, there is no text attribute, so in javascript you can use .html attribute.

```
   $("#releaseNotes").html(('https://buildinfopage.local/app+' + (buildInformation.earVersion.substring(0, buildInformation.earVersion.indexOf('-')))));
```

Comment: This won't create a link. You need to create an `<a>` tag.